# Proving a property of concave functions

Tags: solution-verification

Let $f$ be a concave function. Then, by definition, for any $\alpha \in [0,1]$
\begin{equation}
 f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) \geq \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha) f(y)
\end{equation}

Is there a way to prove that
\begin{equation}
 f(x) + f(y) \leq f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) + f(\alpha y + (1-\alpha) x)
\end{equation}

by using the upper definition?

Comment: You titled this "convex functions" but then talk about "concave functions".  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm fixing the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$\begin{cases}
f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) &\ge  \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha) f(y)\\
f((1-\alpha) x + \alpha y) &\ge  (1-\alpha) f(x) + \alpha f(y)
\end{cases}$$

By adding those two inequalities you get the desired result
$$f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) + f(\alpha y + (1-\alpha) x) \ge f(x)+f(y)$$